# Яке походження слова "фист"?

Tags: етимологія, діалектизми

Слово-діалектизм "[фист](http://halmova.if.ua/dictionary/slovo/3664/)" означає "сильно" (варто зазначати, що в СУМі його немає). Приклад:

> Я фист сі вдарив.

Цікавить звідки це слово прийшло в українську мову? Згідно з інформацією поданою у джерелі, це Галицький діалект, тому можу припустити, що це слово пов'язане з польською мовою. В [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/978-966-00-0197-8/978-966-00-0197-8.pdf) цього слова немає.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Коротко:

З німецької за польським посередництвом.

---

Словники переважно записують як **фест**:

> [<sub>Лексикон львівський</sub>](http://slovopedia.org.ua/101/53412/1067778.html)
>
> **фест** міцний, сильний; дуже добрий, першокласний *(ср, ст)*: Пані *Стефа – фест господиня, таких порядків, як в неї, то ше пошукати, а їдженя таке смачне, але як спитаєш про який пере́пис, то ніколи не дасть* (Авторка); *Там буде фест забава* (Авторка); *Ірця наша має фест сопрано* (Авторка); *Мій вуйко – фест хлоп, сам наші речі за раз виніс на стрих* (Авторка)
>
> ◊ **ма́ти [фест] я́йці** → **яйці**
>
> ◊ **на фест**
>
> 1. дуже сильно, міцно; дуже добре *(ст)*: *Василь дивився на струмок крови, що стікав йому десь з околиці вуха. – Нагла кров! Таки мене парнули! А що буде, як на фест?* (Лисяк); *Хіба треті майстри на фест зробили столярку* (Авторка)
> 2. цілком певно; обовʼязково, точно *(ст)*
>
> ◊ **трима́йся фест** → **тримайся**
>
> ◊ **фест хри́я** → **хрия**

> [Словник лемківскої говірки](http://slovopedia.org.ua/99/53412/1041276.html)
>
> **фест** сильно, дуже багато

Тому легко знаходиться через [польський словник](https://wsjp.pl/index.php?szukaj=fest), котрий вказує і походження:

> *niem.*  'mocny, twardy, trwały'

Також через [ЕСУМ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82):

> **ФЕСТ** «добре; добрий»
>
> - запозичення з польської мови
> - п. fest «здорово; здоровий, сильний» походить від нім. fest «міцний, твердий, сталий, постійний», спорідненого з днн. fast, дфриз. fest, снідерл. шв. дат. vast «тc.», вірм. hast «міцний, сталий», дінд. pastyā́ «будинок і двір», первісно «постійне місце проживання, резиденція», тох. В epastye «умілий, вправний, зручний, підхожий»

---

Про подальше [походження](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fest#Etymology_3):

> From Middle High German *vest*, from Old High German *festi*, from Proto-Germanic *[*fastuz*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/fastuz);

> Connected with Old Armenian հաստ (hast, “firm, steady, standing still, tough; thick, dense, broad”), possibly also Sanskrit पस्त्य *neuter* (pastyá, “stall, stable ← stable habitation”), पस्त्या *feminine* (pastyā́, “homestead, dwelling, household”), and usually derived from Proto-Indo-European **pastV-* (“solid, stable”). Kroonen separates the Sanskrit and reconstructs the Proto-Indo-European root for Armenian and Germanic as **pHst-*, according to him from earlier **ph₂ǵ-sth₂-*, a compound of **peh₂ǵ-* (“to become firm”) (compare Ancient Greek πήγνυμι (pḗgnumi, “to fasten, fix, make solid”)) and **steh₂-* (“to stand”).
>
> However, according to Martirosyan we are hardly dealing with a Proto-Indo-European word. This is rather a substrate word shared by Armenian, Germanic, possibly also Indo-Aryan.

Comment: Я дуже перепрошую за те, що дозволяю собі критикувати Вашу відповідь (адже, здається, вона правильна; і на додачу до того вона єдина — за кілька місяців, що минули з часу написання запитання, ніхто не спромігся написати іншу)… Але, на жаль, за правилами цього сайту (точніше, «батьківського» сайту Stack Exchange, частиною якого ми є і традицій якого ми мусимо дотримуватися), у нас не прийнято писати такі короткі відповіді без обґрунтувань і посилань. Щонайменше вточніть, будь ласка: про походження від нім _fest_ — це Ваша особиста думка чи Ви можете якось аргументувати (на щось послатися)?

Comment: По-друге, було б добре послатися на значення німецького _fest_ у якомусь словнику. (Найголовніше — це, звісно, якось аргументувати походження, але навіть якщо Ви висловлюєте суто особисте відчуття, то хоча б подати докладнішу інформацію про первісне слово було б варто.)

Comment: Дуже дякую вам за відповідь!